# How To Improve RichTextBox Log Write Performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a Log Window with colored text using a `RichTextBox`.

It runs hidden `Hide()` at start until you press a button to bring it up `Show()`.

I was using a `TextBlock before`, but you couldn't select text, so I switched to `RichTextBox`. It has increased the finish time by 5 seconds when before it was almost instant.

How can I improve write speed or defer writing all messages until the end of the program?

Throughout the program I write to the log many times using:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();  

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        rtbLog.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Log Message Example")) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());   
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("Log Message Example 2") { Foreground = Brushes.White });   
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="600" Height="400" Margin="246,10,0,0" Padding="10"
             FontFamily="Consolas" Background="#FF000000"
             Foreground="White" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             IsReadOnly="True" IsUndoEnabled="False"/>
```

To improve speed I've tried using `IsUndoEnabled="False"` and `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"`, it might have reduced the time by 1 second.

[image: log console]

Comment: where is the binding for richtextbox content? I suggest you write into buffer like `StringWriter` and write all the text into richtextbox when `Show()`.

Comment: You could write to a list and only open the log window when you need it then close it instead of keeping it hidden, I can write up an answer tomorrow but I'm on a windows phone now so it I hard to!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I just write to it straight from c# using .Inlines.Add(). Will StringWriter save the bush color information?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I'm trying your idea. Add the paragraph writes to an action list, then execute the list at the end of the program. Maybe you can improve. https://i.imgur.com/Di6JEPf.png

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a list of all the log events around outside of both of the windows and let both class access them so some static class:

```
public static class Logs
{
    public static Paragraph Paragraph { get; set; }

    static Logs()
    {
        Paragraph = new Paragraph();
    }
}
```

Then when you need to write to the logs do something like the following:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    Logs.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    Logs.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Log Message Example")) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
}
```

Then when you want to show the window call:

```
SomeWindow someWindow = new SomeWindow();
someWindow.ShowDialog(); //Or show
```

Then you need a new window class with the `RichTextBox` on it and add the paragraph on start.

```
public class SomeWindow : Window
{
    public SomeWindow()
    {
        rtbLog.Document = new FlowDocument(Logs.Paragraph);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will get back on how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve write performance by adjusting the code.

One problem was using rtbLog.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph) multiple times.

- Put multiple Inline.Add()'s in a List of Actions.
- Create Method that writes all Actions to RichTextBox using foreach loop with BeginChange() & EndChange().
- Optionally put Method in BackgroundWorker.

Speed is now instant.

```
List<Action> LogActions = new List<Action>();
Action WriteAction;


// Create Multiple Actions 
WriteAction = () =>
{
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Example")) { Foreground = Brushes.White });
};
// Add Actions to List
LogActions.Add(WriteAction);


// At End of Program or in a Method:

public void LogWriteAll() {
    // Write All Actions in List
    myWindow.rtbLog.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);

    // Begin Rich Textbox Change
    myWindow.rtbLog.BeginChange();

    foreach (Action Write in LogActions)
    {
        Write();
    }

    myWindow.rtbLog.EndChange();
}
```